# When I put a value in my third text box that time I am getting automatically a value in my second text box with multiply by 10

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, xcode8

When I put a value in my third text box that time I am getting automatically a value in my second text box with multiply by 10 but I do not want to change that value which is appear in second text box.

Following is my code and method and I am sharing two screen one is without error and second is with error.[this is with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1jTV.png)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

{

    _hourlyrate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[_avgsalary.text doubleValue]/208 ];


    _totalMcost.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[_hourlyrate.text doubleValue]*[_pepinMeeting.text doubleValue]*[_hoursOfmeeting.text doubleValue]];


    NSLog(@"avg: %@",_totalMcost.text);

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: You need to check which one of your textField is "being updated": `if (textField == firstTextField){//Do something}else if (textField == secondTextField){//Do something}, etc.`

Comment: still i am getting error @larme this is my code 
    if (textField==_avgsalary) {
           _hourlyrate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[_avgsalary.text doubleValue]/2080];
    }
   else if (textField==_hourlyrate){
    
   _totalMcost.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[_hourlyrate.text doubleValue]*[_pepinMeeting.text doubleValue]*[_hoursOfmeeting.text doubleValue]];
}

Comment: now i am getting error in total .there are not getting right multiplication in total @larme

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access textfield.text in shouldChangeCharectersInRange method, it will give you the old value before replacing the text.

To get the updated value place this code in

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

{

   double hourlyRateValue = 0.0;
   if (textfield == _hourlyrate) {
        hourlyRateValue = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] doubleValue]; // Use this value for calculation

   }
    return YES;

}
```

Please note that I have written this code in plain text editor. Check the syntax.